# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type Collection of List

Tags: c#, json, firebase-realtime-database

I'm converting json to list of Model in C#, but this is making exception, In my Json response , i'm receiving GUID type, i don't know how to convert in model binding.

```
    client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
    FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Products/");
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(response.Body);
    Products obj = response.ResultAs<Products>();
    var listOfProducts = response.ResultAs<List<Products>>();
    return View(listOfProducts);





  The below is my Json response,

    {"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C":{"categories":"Featured|Fish|Rice","productDescription":"New complete product\nThis is the test description to check how much space is taken by it. So just filling some random thing here and there. Also we need to limit the size of the description based on how much space it can take else admin can enter a very big description just like this. :)","productImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","productName":"Schezwan Fried Rice","sizes":[{"goodFor":1,"price":"7.77","size":"Small"},{"goodFor":2,"price":"8.88","size":"Medium"},{"goodFor":3,"price":"9.99","size":"Large"}],"stockAmount":"Yes"},"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041":{"categories":"Chicken|Rice|Featured","productDescription":"Fried rice dish","productImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","productName":"Fried Rice ","sizes":[{"goodFor":1,"price":"2.95","size":"Small"},{"goodFor":2,"price":"3.95","size":"Medium"},{"goodFor":3,"price":"4.95","size":"Large"}],"stockAmount":"Yes"}}



 i've another response, what will be the code to extract below response,

{"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3":{"02CBD688-C6F9-44B1-A62F-EDC6EE685DE8":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"19.98","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$9.99","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521278785.31225","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"27.75","orderUserAddress":"test5, city5, 55555, state5","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"054B7B1A-0F7A-49E9-BCAC-CC20E63538D1":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"5.90","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.90","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$3.95","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1537453527.02233","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"13.80","orderUserAddress":"test5, city5, 55555, state5","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"0872BD6B-F5FE-4036-A6B0-9D19AE8ECD31":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"26.64","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"3"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521277982.70246","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"26.64","orderUserAddress":"doing test address, tedt, 123456, test","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"1A7E73C5-B9A1-4162-9812-2154142C287D":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"17.76","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$3.95","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521317743.81503","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"25.66","orderUserAddress":"test5, city5, 55555, state5","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"1F54A117-F7E9-4B2E-876F-9D1135904F11":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"26.64","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"3"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1520756940.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"26.64","orderUserAddress":"doing test address, tedt, 123456, test","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"2E650B47-7F6F-4D5F-8D2E-F8674F99A37A":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"26.64","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"3"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1520759280.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"26.64","orderUserAddress":"doing test address, tedt, 123456, test","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"4380CE47-9F2A-4573-8B07-74117588AC83":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"2.95","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"3.95","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$3.95","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"8.88","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"9.99","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$9.99","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"1"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521294456.67573","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"33.54","orderUserAddress":"doing test address, tedt, 123456, test","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"854FC878-77D2-40D7-8096-7135F12A6E81":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"29.97","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$9.99","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"3"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521294647.52492","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"Asia/Kolkata","orderTotalAmount":"37.74","orderUserAddress":"test5, city5, 55555, state5","phoneNumber":"(973) 194-4040","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"},"C2FB998F-341A-4FAD-90AB-A5C6226B1FD4":{"email":"nimitknd@gmail.com","fullname":"Nimit Kalaria","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1519554240.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"7.77","orderUserAddress":"doing test address, tedt, 123456, test","phoneNumber":"1234567890","userId":"EYr9acl0M4YYE08k426TKNPbv8J3"}},"fiCJGAaBVqg70zD7Ahk2LKt57A33":{"056B0822-F0A0-4F05-AF72-A9A4280CAE2A":{"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"14.75","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"5"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$3.95","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"9.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$4.95","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"19.98","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$9.99","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1513253700.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"60.3","userId":"fiCJGAaBVqg70zD7Ahk2LKt57A33"},"69101F56-D176-433A-A27F-F8F604C15118":{"orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"5.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1519113480.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"5.9","orderUserAddress":"3 Enterprise Drive, Stratford , 06615, CT","phoneNumber":"44444444444","userId":"fiCJGAaBVqg70zD7Ahk2LKt57A33"},"A4BA58B8-8F80-4E9B-AAB6-F2245278C8E1":{"orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"5.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1518767640.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"5.9","orderUserAddress":"3 Enterprise Drive, Stratford , 06615, CT","phoneNumber":"646283234","userId":"fiCJGAaBVqg70zD7Ahk2LKt57A33"},"ED0B9D33-2F93-4A35-BFB6-4B5A367B76C4":{"email":"olunic@gmail.com","fullname":"Olu","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"14.75","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"5"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$3.95","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"9.9","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$4.95","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"2"},{"orderItemAmount":"7.77","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$7.77","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"1"},{"orderItemAmount":"19.98","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$9.99","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"2"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1515240720.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"60.3","phoneNumber":"123445566","userId":"fiCJGAaBVqg70zD7Ahk2LKt57A33"}},"mRqzmatsBuRrwiJIJ6w2MUe7yx33":{"3419F8B9-BDF3-4148-9DC9-685C0EBFCE39":{"email":"onicholson@hostfiniti.net","fullname":"olu n","orderIsDelivery":true,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"44.4","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"5"},{"orderItemAmount":"29.5","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"10"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1520432040.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"73.90","orderUserAddress":"7 Warwick Ave, stratfor, 06615, cy","phoneNumber":"6462832242","userId":"mRqzmatsBuRrwiJIJ6w2MUe7yx33"},"8A84E8AD-C4C4-4B47-AFB0-39880A056932":{"email":"onicholson@hostfiniti.net","fullname":"olu n","orderIsDelivery":false,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"44.4","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2F806CACEC-4D99-4EF5-935E-E4FAD8A6529C%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=90a64e8c-f03c-43ee-8bdb-ea4b3334912d","orderItemName":"Fried Rice","orderItemPrice":"$8.88","orderItemSize":"Medium","orderQuantity":"5"},{"orderItemAmount":"29.5","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$2.95","orderItemSize":"Regular","orderQuantity":"10"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1520463900.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"73.90","phoneNumber":"6462832242","userId":"mRqzmatsBuRrwiJIJ6w2MUe7yx33"}},"ue6N51P9OFOrQgRBgutmJ48Hky22":{"667D44AF-FB0D-4656-8392-47DBAFFDE564":{"email":"onicholson@hostfiniti.org","fullname":"olu nic","orderIsDelivery":false,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"19.8","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$4.95","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"4"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1520464680.0","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/Chicago","orderTotalAmount":"19.80","phoneNumber":"16462832242","userId":"ue6N51P9OFOrQgRBgutmJ48Hky22"},"91F01103-9924-4B09-A325-A3B46F2B9536":{"email":"onicholson@hostfiniti.org","fullname":"olu nic","orderIsDelivery":false,"orderItems":[{"orderItemAmount":"19.8","orderItemCategory":"RICE","orderItemCode":"F977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041","orderItemImage":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amrestaurant-c56b4.appspot.com/o/Products%2FF977ADF3-7820-4CC6-9A11-B59CA7D62041%2Fimage0?alt=media&token=798c6a99-3cf9-45d2-abd5-9da9593cb8e1","orderItemName":"Fried Rice ","orderItemPrice":"$4.95","orderItemSize":"Large","orderQuantity":"4"}],"orderPaymentMode":"Cash","orderStatus":"On the way","orderTimestamp":"1521358768.40113","orderTimezoneIdentifier":"America/New_York","orderTotalAmount":"19.80","phoneNumber":"(164) 628-3224","userId":"ue6N51P9OFOrQgRBgutmJ48Hky22"}}}

And this is my model,

        public class Products
        {
            public string categories { get; set; }
            public string productDescription { get; set; }
            public string productImage { get; set; }
            public string productName { get; set; }
            public List<Sizes> sizes { get; set; }
            public string stockAmount { get; set; }
        }
        public class Sizes
        {
            public int goodFor { get; set; }
            public decimal price { get; set; }
            public string size { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the GUID key, the returned data can be converted to a `Dictionary<string, Propducts>` and the desired data extracted from the parsed dictionary

```
//...

FirebaseClient client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Products/");
Dictionary<string, Products> data = response.ResultAs<Dictionary<string, Products>>();
List<Products>() listOfProducts = data.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
return View(listOfProducts);
```

While the original data shown has one result. The above answer will also work when the object has multiple keys when the response has more than one item.

Comment: Hi @@Nkosi, can you see the above one more response, i've added, can you also give the code of above response.

Answer (score 1):

A collection would be `[{},{}]`.

Your input is a single object.

It very common to wrap collections in an object before returning them (it's linked to [security](https://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html?m=1), search for 'top level json arrays').

---

You may need to create a wrapper object

```
public WithProducts {
public List<Products> Products { get; set; } // Guessing. See what the collection is called in the result
}
(...)

JsonConvert.Deserialise<WithProducts>(json);
```

---

Btw. It's good practice to use a singular noun for class names e.g. `Product`, `Size` so you don't end up with `var oneProduct = new Products() {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, can you more elaborate it for the solution, i'm confused still now.